Does 'Bloodlust' ability trigger after the unit with that ability is destroyed?
Hunting Instinct's ability Bloodlust1 says:

After this unit destroys a unit an opponent controls by attacking place 1 Red Rains token on the Chimera.

If Hunting Instinct destroys a unit an opponent controls by attacking while Hunting Instinct is as well destroyed due to the countering of the unit it attacks, does its effect trigger, i.e. 1 Red Rain Token is placed on the Chimera?
I assume it doesn't because the Hunting Instinct is no longer in play and so isn't its ability. But maybe it does. From what text in which rule book can I derive the answer to this question?
